# How to pre-select a drop down option list based on the parent key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have two entities Rack and Server. Where each server has a foreign key to the parent rack. Currently I am assigning a server to a Rack, using a drop down list as follow inside the server create view.
The Server Create action method looks as follow:-

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            PopulateViewBagData();

            return View(new ServerJoin() { IsIPUnique = true,
            IsMACUnique = true});
        }
```

Part of the server create view which include a drop down list to select the Rack as follow:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.ServerJoin
<div>
   <span class="f"> Rack</span>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Server.RackID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TMSRack>)ViewBag.Racks).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Technology.Tag), 
        Value = option.TMSRackID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model.Server != null) && (option.TMSRackID == Model.Server.RackID)
    }), "Choose...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.RackID)
</div>
```

What I am trying to implement , is that Inside the rack view I want to add a link to add a server, and to force the Rack drop down list to select the current Rack , something such as:-

```
@HTML.Actionlink(“Create Server under this rack”, “Create”,”Server”, new {rackID = Model.RackID},null)
```

But I am not sure how to force the drop down list to select the rackID passed, baring in mind that the user can still create a server without going to a Rack, the rackID will be null??

Any idea how to implement this ?
BR

Comment: You need to post the code to your Rack view as well. But for now, your `ViewBag.Racks` should contain the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. You shouldn't be having a query in your View. That should be in your Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you should do it:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? rackID)
{
    var model = new ServerJoin() { IsIPUnique = true, IsMACUnique = true};
    if(rackID.HasValue)
    {
       model.RackID = rackID.Value;
    }
    PopulateViewBagData();

    return View(model);
}
```

Then, in your View, you can use an if clause to replace the DropDownList with a Hidden input if the Model has a RackID.

The `ActionLink` in your Rack View is correct.